# How do I let user to correct the error while executing bunch of task via bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to automate a bunch of tasks Task_1, Task_2, Task_3, Task_4, Task_5 -

```
status = Task_1
if (status == FALSE)
   *give option for user to rectify the problem, once done, proceed to Task_2*
status = Task_2
if (status == FALSE)
   *give option for user to rectify the problem, once done, proceed to Task_3*
status = Task_3
if (status == FALSE)
   *give option for user to rectify the problem, once done, proceed to Task_4*
status = Task_4
if (status == FALSE)
   *give option for user to rectify the problem, once done, proceed to Task_5*
status = Task_5
```

How do I achieve the goal of -
"*give option for user to rectify the problem, once done, proceed to Task_X*"
?

Edit:

I am looking at a functionality something similar to that of -

1. you execute git pull --rebase,
2. If there is a merge issue, then it notifies user and let them take action.
3. Once the user corrects, they can execute, git rebase --continue to continue with the rebase process where it was left.

Comment: Do you want to pause the script, show a message to the user, and let them press a key to continue?

Comment: The code posted is not Bash. Use `man -P"less +/compound\ commands" bash` to get information about Bash compound commands including if statements.

Comment: @thatotherguy I am looking at a functionality something similar to that of -
1. you execute git pull --rebase, 
2. If there is a merge issue, then it notifies user and let them take action.
3. Once the user corrects, they can execute, git rebase --continue to continue with the rebase process where it was left.

Answer (score 1):

In general, commands have an exit status. If your tasks are well written, the exit status should be non-zero if the task fails, and zero if the task succeeds. So, in bash you would write something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
if Task_1 ; then
    echo 'Task_1 succeeded'
else
    #give option to rectify the problem
fi
```

and so on for the remaining tasks.

You can also use the exit-code of the last task, `$?`, as in

```
Task_1
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
    echo "Despair! Task_1 has failed"
    # allow the user to do some reparations
fi
```

Giving the user the option to repair depends quite a bit on how that is done and what your environment is.

For example, you could present a menu with fixed actions, like:

```
echo "a for abandon hope, b for be despaired"
read line
case "$line" in
("a")
    # actions for abandoning hope
    ;;
("b")
    # actions for being despaired
    ;;
("*")
    echo "Unknown action; continuing without doing anything."
    ;;
esac
```

or, sometimes you can just launch an xterm:

```
echo "Close terminal when the repair is finished"
xterm
```

(sorry for the gloomy examples)